# Blazor Server cooperation with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to connect Blazor Server functionality with socket.io, which normally is hosted on Node.js. I'd like to use Blazor which will listen to socket.io traffic on certain port.
I don't want to use Node.js, because I have already Blazor Server running on my machine.

According to socket.io documentation, using ES Modules, I may create index.js with listening code:

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

I'm able to reuse npm packages in Blazor application, injecting IJSRuntime on Blazor page and using construction such as:

```
var output = await JsRunTime.InvokeAsync<string>("function");
```

I don't know how to properly glue socket.io into Blazor app (or whether is it even feasible ?)

Should I just add another port while initializing Blazor in CreateHostBuilder, sth like :

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5821;http://localhost:3000");
                webBuilder.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true");
            });
```

and later just listen to port 3000 to intercept socket.io packages ?

thanks !

Comment: You have so much going on here! Have you looked into SignalR instead to keep everything in C#/.NET? I mean I personally dig Socket.IO and Node.js, but it would make your life so much easier to stick with the same tech stack. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly

Comment: @CoryPodojil The problem is, the device I'm using to send the stream is using Socket.IO library. That's why I'm sticking to socket.io. Finally, I have run Node.js server in parallel to Blazor app. Thanks !

Comment: It is going to be a pain to work with JS interop. Not to mention all the security flaws you may create if you are not careful. You should definitely look into setting up SignalR on the device. ASP.NET Core is available on all operating systems.

Comment: @Grizzlly I am actually looking for something similar to Maciej here because my hosting platform runs node.js application, but it doesn't run anything that's .net. So I can create a Blazor WASM app since it runs client-side, and create an Express API with Socket.IO for chat functionality.